# Ionic3(Angular4) CORS on an emulator

Tags: angular, http, cross-domain, ionic3

I'm testing Ionic 3 app on a genymotion emulator.
Btw http request doesn't work because of CORS.
I thought that a sever has a problem.
But I confirmed that a server has no problem after checking it with ionic 2 app.
Http request of Ionic 3 app works well on a real device and on a browser.
Would you like to let me know what I am wrong?
sorry for my poor english.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under your config.xml give the location of your localhost

eg:

```
<content src="http://10.10.1.1:8100" />
<access origin="http://10.10.1.1:8100" />
<allow-navigation href="http://10.10.1.1:8100" />
```

further more make sure you add the proxy url under ionic.config.json

```
"proxies": [{
        "path": "/rest",
        "proxyUrl": "http://10.10.10.1:8081/rest"
    }]
```