# CORS Hell in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, cors, ionic3

I have a backend server (Spring Boot, proxied by nginx) that my Ionic application communicates with. With every single request, it sends the following headers: `access-control-request-headers: *`, `access-control-allow-headers: *`, `access-control-allow-origin: *`, `access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH`. No exceptions.

It also allows `OPTIONS` requests and returns HTTP 200 for every one of them.

Now, I have an ionic app that uses `@angular/common/http`. In browser, everything works fine, I can make `GET` and `POST` requests gracefully.

But in emulator (when I run with `ionic cordova emulate ios`, I can only make `GET` requests, `POST`s fail with the following:

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

As you can see, it says `status: 0`. This refers to a `CORS` issue, but I don't know how to further debug this.

My requests all succeed with Postman, and even with `curl`. It's only in emulator they fail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic3(Angular4) CORS on an emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463186/ionic3angular4-cors-on-an-emulator)

Comment: @HikmatGurbanli It is not. Did you even dare to read and compare the questions? I cannot use a proxy, as I am preparing to deploy my application. And every step in the referred question is already taken to no luck.

Comment: This is an oldie but a goodie: https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/.  This states there is no origin when running on device, thus CORS shouldn't come into play.  Can you confirm there is no OPTIONS request when running in the emulator?  Have you tried on a physical device?

Comment: @BRass Thanks, I am well aware of that page. As I stated, I cannot use a proxy, as stated on the blog. I am going to deploy. I can make `GET` requests, the problem is only with `POSTS`. The link you provided refers to the problem in general, where I have already taken all the steps mentioned. Though, only `GET`s are working. Thanks again.

Comment: Except length of the text seems same, no server issue works on browser, but not emulator. And you haven't mentioned if you have tried that

Comment: The status of 0 may be what you're getting on the ionic/angular level.  Have you confirmed things on the HTTP request level (watch the actual HTTP traffic)?  I've seen libraries hook into Angular that step on the actual HTTP status, leaving Ionic thinking it's a status 0.  From what you have above I would be open to thinking this may be something other than CORS.

Comment: @HikmatGurbanli I am experiencing the same problem in the device as well.

Comment: @BRass `status: 0` means that the request is not made. I might agree that this might not be related to `CORS`.

Comment: `status: 0` in the Angular/Ionic layer does not necessarily mean the request is not made.  Here's an example where an angular2-jwt module was stripping the actual HTTP response (HTTP 4xx's and 5xx's), and Angular got a `status: 0`.  https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CORS` again, I am hoping that this might help someone:

Apparently wildcard(`*`) value for `Acccess-Control-Allow-Headers` header is only accepted in May 2016 ([reference1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-cors-20140116/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header), [reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146892/cors-access-control-allow-headers-wildcard-being-ignored)), so some browsers might still not support it. So, changing from:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

to

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Auth-Token
```

(basically, the exact value of headers my application uses), I was able to resolve the issue. Apparently browser I am using on my desktop supports the wildcard header value, but the browser of the emulator and device doesn't. Definitely not a device vs. emulator issue, but a browser vs. browser issue.

Comment: Anyone coming here should also notice that same goes for `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header as well.